# Can one get tax credit or deduction if they pay for the relative's university education?

Tags: germany, taxes

I'm going to pay for my brother's university tuition next year. He will study in a German university. I am working in Germany. Am I allowed to file the tuition as tax return for myself?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if the rules have changed but when I lived in Germany back in early 2000 you could deduct school fees for your own children up to 30% of the cost and you could deduct personal education for yourself or spouse to further educate yourself.

There was no deduction for other family members at that time from your personal income tax as far as I am aware, but rules do change so lets see what someone with a more recent experience have to say.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica your own children I just edited to clarify

Comment: Thanks for the clarity!

Comment: Sonce people usually don't by tuition fees for their siblings (but their parents would do), is this a case where you are financially responsible for your brother, for example if the parents are dead? It's not "parents" but "legal guardians", so OP could be the legal guardian of his brother.